# plasma-nm can't be installed and there is no wifi icon after upgrading the OS

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager, kde, 22.04

I've just upgraded my kubuntu(KDE plasma) from 21.10 to 22.04 LTS. But after a successful installation and rebooting my system, the wifi icon disappeared and `plasma-nm` is not installed. 
I tried to install the `plasma-nm` using `sudo apt install plasma-nm`, but I received the following messages and it didn't install.

```
Package plasma-nm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  kubuntu-settings-desktop

E: Package 'plasma-nm' has no installation candidate
```

Well, after a break, I decided to install the `plasma-nm` manually by downloading and installing its `.deb` file with the help of `sudo dpkg -i plasma-nm_5.12.4-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb`. After this attempt, I received the following error which shows the dependencies are gone!

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plasma-nm:
plasma-nm depends on libkf5modemmanagerqt6 (>= 5.8.50); however:
 Package libkf5modemmanagerqt6:amd64 is not installed.
plasma-nm depends on libopenconnect5 (>= 7.05); however:
 Package libopenconnect5 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package plasma-nm (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 plasma-nm
```

Finally, I could connect my wifi using `nmcli con up <My wifi name> --ask` and posting my problem :). But the wifi icon is not still there and I can't install `plasma-nm`.
In the end I'm sorry for my weak English -_- 
Thnx for help.

Comment: are you using Kubuntu or KDE Plasma? Kubuntu is an official Ubuntu flavor and on-topic here, but KDE Plasma is not.

Comment: also the messages very clearly say that `kubuntu-settings-desktop` has replaced `plasma-nm`.